# Find example of nonhomogeneous ideal in $\mathbb{k}[x]$ which has two different minimal generating sets are not equipotent.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I have problem with finding example of nonhomogeneous ideal in $\mathbb{k}[x]$ with two different minimal generating sets which are not equipotent.

Is there any general way to find such examples?

Is for example ideal generated by $x^7+1$ and $x^7-1$ a good example as it is also generated by $x^7$ alone?

Comment: The ideal generated by $x^7+1$ and $x^7-1$ is generated by $1$, actually.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path, right. What about $x+x^3$ and $x^5$? It is also generated by $x$ alone. Although it is as good as my initial example. So either they both good or wrong.